# Augmented reality - replacing elements on the screen

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

my goal is to make an augmented reality app, which will take a specific element in the view and replace it with something else.

For example it will replace your television with a new one and you will be able to see how it fits into your living room. Could you please suggest me some materials, articles, whatever to study? (ideally for both Android and iOS) Thanks.